# How to generate a second table view when the user touches a cell in the first (dynamic) table view (in Objective-C)?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a table view with dynamic cells generated in the class TableViewController. I made a segue to another table view (which inherits from TableViewController2). I want to trigger the display of the new table view when the user selects a cell from the first table view. I implemented prepareForSegue in TableViewController. The segue works, I can see the first table view pop off screen and the new table view pop in, but it's empty whatever I do. How can I trigger the display of the cells in TableViewController2?

In TableViewController:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    if ([(segue.identifier) isEqualToString:@"topSegue"]){

        TableViewController2 *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        TableViewController2 *tvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

In TableViewController2:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Top 50 list";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is it clear enough? If not, I can ask questions. I really need help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the following two methods in your second tvc?

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

and

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView